# How to exhibit a json with internal vectors?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

So, I have to split a json, but I don't know how. I need that the name of a category goes shows in a tab. Here's a example of my json:

```
 "tabs": [
           {
            "General": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2019-11-29 11:32:11",
                    "name":'Test 1'
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2019-11-29 11:32:11",
                    "name":'Test 2'
                },

            ]
           },
           {
            "One More": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2019-11-29 15:01:55",
                    "name": "Test 3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

The tab code I understand (is like this: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/), my problem is just show "General" or "One More" on the tab name, and the name changes... I know is a silly question, but I can't find a good explanation.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You want to display a tab for each key of `tabs`?

Comment: Yup, I had a code to handle this, my problem is just the name of the tab, how to access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/) to render one tab for each `key` of `tabs`

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="profile" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
    {
        Object.keys(tabs).map(key =>(
            <Tab title={key} key={key}>
                Foo
             </Tab>
        ))
    }
</Tabs>
```

`Object.keys(myObject)` will provide you an array of strings representing each property of the original object

Comment: Thanks, It helps a lot!!! I never uses the Object.keys to map, just the array itself!